# Javascript nested function composition

Tags: javascript, inheritance, composition

I used to do this with classes, where a child class i.e. **ChildObj** can be extended from the parent class i.e. **ParentObj** in a brand new class that has all the functionality of the parent and replaces only one method i.e. **JobA** using function overriding thru inheritance.

Now with JS functional programming, I have a problem. How to replace the old function **JobA** that is called from the Parent from a new composed function?

NOTE: The **parentObj** ie **init** is **a 3rd party library** that I don't want to make any kind of modifications. I just want to make my current code (based on the Class Extensions) compatible with the new versions of the library that replaced the original classes with functions.

```
// Original code in main.js
var ParentObj = init;

function init(){
    function JobA() {
        console.log("JobA");
    }
    
    function JobB() {
        console.log("JobB");
    }
    
    console.log("Init");
    JobA(); //I want the called JobA HERE, to be the child's JobA
    JobB();
}

// Extending it by replacing and wrapping, in extended.js
ParentObj = ( function(parent) {
    function JobA() {
        console.log("Child JobA");
    }

    function extendsInit() {
        parent();
        console.log("The extension");
    }

    return extendsInit;
})(ParentObj);


ParentObj();
```

Quote from React Team :
https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: Functional programming and composition are orthogonal. The quote refers to [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) which is equally valid in OOP context. It was most notably expressed in the book *Design Patterns* which is all about OOP. The problem you've stated in the question is also not really to do with "composition" or "inheritance". The whole structure is weird. Why is `init` creating and calling the functions? It should simply receive an object and call `input.jobA()` which will then work whether `input` is a ParentObj or a ChildObj.

Comment: @VLAZ, This is a special case in my point of view that composition just fails. The Init is a 3rd party library and I just want to change the behavior of the JobA. With the old version of the library, I did what exactly described. In this case? What?

Comment: If `init` is third party tool and *does not expose a mechanism for overriding a call*, then that's not a failure of composition. You'd have exactly the same problem if it was using inheritance but did not expose a way to override something. Seems the entire premise of the question here is wrong. If you don't control the code for `init`, then you cannot magically make it behave differently. Unless you start hacking at it which is extremely brittle and inadvisable.

Comment: @VLAZ That's somewhat true, BUT with the previous version of the library (based on Classes) I had the flexibility that now I don't. The author of the library had a public method that I could always extend for some reason. He just converted the old code to new without taking in mind the consequences for the rest of us. Do I have this option now? I suppose no. That makes the whole thing complicated. From my side, its a fail.

Comment: That's not a feature of functions or compositions, though. It's the author simply not exposing this. *Again*, this could have also been the case with inheritance. So, all the talk about functional programming and composition is completely irrelevant here. What *is* relevant that `init` is not something you actually control. Yet you've not shared this information in the question itself.

Comment: @VLAZ yes you have right, I just mention the composition since I could not find any other way to move on since Classes here are obsolete. I will add the last comment to my question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* in parent "class" */
this.JobA = function() {};

/* in the extendsInit method */
parent();
overrideMethods();

function overrideMethods(){
    this.JobA = function(){
         console.log('I\'m the overridden method!');
    }
}
```

That could emulate an inheritance in your solution...

Comment: This is not the case. The Init is a 3rd party library and I want to change the behavior of the JobA only, nothing else.

Comment: In javascript if you define a function(){} it saves all function as a string... so if you want to ovverride a nested function you have to rewrite the parent too. But if you define a instance related function with this.JobA that changes a lot and it permits you to ovveride that method

Comment: That's correct, but in my case, I don't want to rewrite the parent code or copy/paste the whole function just to change a single line. The original library code should remain unchanged for future updates. That's why I am using classes for my apps. I was looking for another solution than this.

Comment: @Maverick allright then try using JobA = eval(init.toString().replace( /* replace pattern */); That permit you to evaluate as a string the initial function, then modify it, and eval() transform the result string into another function... if you replaced things without errrors

Comment: It's a solution but I really don't like it from the side of readability, and extensibility.
 I tend to rewrite the parent code.....

Comment: I agree with you... but there is not other solutions to get, and ovverride, a local declared function from an external context :-(

Comment: That's why composition in this case fails in my opinion. Using Classes, you always have an option to overcome this obstacle.